# Postman Collection Format v1 is no longer supported and can not be imported directlyYou may convert ur collection to Formatv2 and try importing again

Tags: postman

I need your help. I have this error, I managed to convert the .json file from version 1.0.0 to version 2.0.0.0 with the following command at the prompt

```
C:\Users\AC\Desktop\test>postman-collection-transformer convert -i test.json -o prueba1.json -j 1.0.0 -p 2.0.0 -P
```

[In the following url is the collection that I converted and the one that after making the changes in Visual, it doesn't update.](https://www.postman.com/collections/ffcbfb5c8d5cd2dc52d2) and when I send the request, the file is not updated with the changes that I specify in Visual Studio Code, I don’t know what could be going wrong. Why Postman doesn't allow version 1.0.0?

[Capture Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdaI8.png)

[Anaconda run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Fhk.png)

[In this image it should return me an id, not that phrase. It's as if after the conversion something is lost.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfAaE.png)

Answer (score 4):

it won't update the file it will create a new collection file :

```
postman-collection-transformer convert -i old_collection.json -o new_collection.json -j 1.0.0 -p 2.0.0 -P
```

the above command converts the v1 "old_collection.json" file and creates a new_collection.json

Comment: hello, this is what I did and it doesn't solve the problem for me, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Please explain.the problem more.clearly it's.hard to.undedstan